# Presto cluster on Kubernetes error worker bind port 8080

Tags: docker, kubernetes, presto, minikube

I'm setting up a Presto cluster with 1 coordinator and 1 worker. I have used the same own images only with Docker and it worked.

However, when I pass to Kubernetes I get an error in the worker node when initialising Presto:

> ERROR main com.facebook.presto.server.PrestoServer
>
> Unable to create injector, see the following errors:
>
> 1) Error in custom provider, java.lang.NullPointerException
>     at com.facebook.airlift.discovery.client.DiscoveryBinder.bindServiceAnnouncement(DiscoveryBinder.java:79)
>
> while locating com.facebook.airlift.discovery.client.ServiceAnnouncement annotated with @com.google.inject.internal.Element(setName=,uniqueId=146, type=MULTIBINDER, keyType=)
>     while locating java.util.Set
>
> 3) Error injecting constructor, java.io.UncheckedIOException: Failed to bind to /0.0.0.0:8080
>     at com.facebook.airlift.http.server.HttpServerInfo.(HttpServerInfo.java:48)

deployment

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: presto-cluster
  namespace: presto-clu2
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: presto-c
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: presto-c
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: presto-co
        image: x/openjdk-presto-k:1.0
        imagePullPolicy: Always
        ports:
        - containerPort: 8080
      - name: presto-wo
        image: x/openjdk-prestoworker-k:1.0
        imagePullPolicy: Always
        ports:
        - containerPort: 8181
```

service

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: presto-cluster
  namespace: presto-clu2
spec:
  selector:
    app: presto-c
  ports:
  - protocol: TCP
    port: 8080
    targetPort: 8080
  type: NodePort
```

When going up with namespace, service and deployment only the coordinator gets operative.

It seems something related to the worker not being able to bind in port `8080` for the discovery of the coordinator. I know that inside a pod, all containers share ports and that could be the issue here, but I don't know well enough the technologies to check it and potentially change the port in the worker.

Do you have any idea of the issue?

Comment: The error talks about binding failure with port 8080. You seem to have the worker bind to 8081, how are you concluding the worker failed?

Comment: Running two containers in a single pod like this isn't usually a best practice; if both are trying to run as port 8080 that would produce this error (the pod has a single network namespace and the program running inside the container isn't aware of the pod configuration unless it's told to use a different port via command-line arguments or environment variables).

Comment: The line of defining port 8181 was only a test from previous docker setting but it's not tied to anything configured in the worker. (   Last State:     Terminated
      Reason:       Error
      Exit Code:    1) Actually, I have quitted it to see if it has some effect but the error is still the same. I'll try with different pods and see what happens, thanks ;)

Comment: Can you provide output of `kubectl get events` and `kubectl describe pod <pod name>`

Comment: Name:         presto-cluster-66958cf6c4-b88m7
Namespace:    presto-clu2
Priority:     0
Node:         minikube/192.168.64.3
Start Time:   Mon, 20 Jan 2020 21:53:32 +0100
Labels:       app=presto-c
              pod-template-hash=66958cf6c4
Annotations:  <none>
Status:       Running
IP:           172.17.0.6
IPs:
  IP:           172.17.0.6
Controlled By:  ReplicaSet/presto-cluster-66958cf6c4

Comment: Containers:
  presto-co:
    Container ID:   docker://
    Image:          x/openjdk-presto-k:1.0
    Image ID:     
    Port:           8080/TCP
    Host Port:      0/TCP
    State:          Running
      Started:      Mon, 20 Jan 2020 21:53:37 +0100
    Ready:          True
    Restart Count:  0
    Environment:    <none>
    Mounts:
        presto-wo:
    Container ID:  
    Image:          x/openjdk-prestoworker:1.0
    Image ID:       
    Port:           <none>
    Host Port:      <none>
    State:          Running
      Started:      
    Last State:     Terminated

Comment: change `http-server.http.port` in your `config.properties` file for worker to something different

Comment: yes, that's it. It's only necessary to change the bind port of the worker to for example 8081. Thanks